# Best way to parse complex configuration file

Tags: python, parsing, grammar

I need to parse a complex configuration file using Python.  I should note that the format of these files is something I cannot change, but rather have to live with.

The basic structure of the file is this:

```
Keyword1
"value1"
thisisirrelevantforkeyword1
Keyword2
"first", "second", "third"
1, 2, 3

Keyword3
2, "whatever"
firstparam, 1
secondparam, 2
again_not_relevant
```

Ultimately, the output of this should be a JSON string.

Let me explain:

- Each keyword has its own rules.
- The values are in the line(s) following the keyword.
- For example, *Keyword1* has one value, which is the string *value1*.  The line following *value1* is irrelevant.
- For example, *Keyword2* has two parameters, the first one being a list of strings, the second one a list of integers.
- For example, *Keyword3* has a variable number of parameters, being indicated by the first integer in the first line after *Keyword3*.  So the parameters relevant for *Keyword3* are the list *2, "whatever"*, and the two lists in the two following lines.

There is a fixed set of keywords with its own rules.  Of course, I could in principle hard-code the whole thing, which would lead to a lot of code duplication.  Plus, this would be quite inflexible regarding new keywords, or changing rules for single keywords.

I'd rather prepare a CSV file containing all keywords, with the rule how it is defined, and then use this as input for a more generic parser function.

So my question is:
- How do I specify the rules in a simple way?  I'm sure there's standards for this, but have absolutely no idea where to start looking.
- How could I then use this grammar to parse the file and generate my JSON?

I know this is a quite specific, special, and complex thing; so I'd already be thankful for pointers in the right direction, as I feel a bit lost and am unsure where to start looking.

Comment: You should at least take a stab at this. Use a finite state machine model. For each line, if it's a keyword, use that keyword section's parsing routines. If it's not a keyword, pass to the current keyword section's parsing routines. Let us know what you come up with.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could have some classes for your options which have really special rules.

Something like that :

```
class OptionBase(object):
    def __init__(self, name, **options):
        self.name = name
        self.raw_config_lines = []

    def parse_line(self, line):
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            self.raw_config_lines.append(line)

    def get_config(self):
        raise Exception('Not Implemented')


class SimpleOption(OptionBase):
    def __init__(self, name, **options):
        super(SimpleOption, self).__init__(name, **options)
        self.expected_format = options.get('expected_format', str)

    def parse_line(self, line):
        if len(self.raw_config_lines):
            raise Exception('SimpleOption can only have one value')
        else:
            super(SimpleOption, self).parse_line(line)

    def get_config(self):
        return None if not self.raw_config_lines else self.expected_format(self.raw_config_lines[0])


class SomeComplexOption(OptionBase):
    def parse_line(self, line):
        #some special code which verify number of lines, type of args etc.

    def get_config(self):
        #some code to transform raw_line in another format
```